# CORDA booting in my world

Tags: corda

**Background**-
I am extremely new to CORDA and Blockchain Platform. In the past few months i have had my share of experience working on a small project on Ethereum as platform. Ethereum blockchain was leveraged as ledger to mark Transaction as a proof of existence. It means for some action (success/failure) we have marked respective transaction on Blockchain. We may consider it as a proof of concept to show knowledge of interaction with nodes running on Ethereum Blockchain.
**Infrastructure** - Node.js web services, two ethereum (PoA) nodes

**Question**-
I would now like to port this running example on to CORDA blockchain. How would i achieve this with bare minimum changes. That means if i have a Corda network with two nodes running on my system and i want my web services to connect to one or both of the nodes and save the transaction (in its state). I understand that this certainly is not what CORDA might be meant for. Consider this question as my first step to interact with CORDA from Node.js web services.

Any inputs highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you go through the documentation first. your Tx will be a state. you need to build contracts and flows for a Tx to happen. Tx will happen using flows which will be initiated using Crash Shell or RPC Client. AFAIK, this client is in Kotlin or Java. so you'll have to create a JAVA or Kotlin application to instantiate this client. now in the Java application, you'll have to expose rest endpoints to communicate with the client which will initiate your flows. you can call these rest endpoints from your node application. All this has to be created in CodaApp. This is the bare minimum.

I just found there is a library.

look at this: https://gitlab.com/bluebank/braid
This can help you.